# IDB_BITMAP1 is undefined

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

[IDB_BITMAP1 is undefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVfap.png)

I'm trying to learn to use resources in VC++.

I added a bitmap and called it IDB_BITMAP1. However, I keep getting warnings that IDB_BITMAP1 is undefined.

Here is my resource.h file:

```
//{{NO_DEPENDENCIES}}

// Microsoft Visual C++ generated include file.
// Used by gdiplustest.rc
//
#define IDC_MYICON                      2
#define IDD_GDIPLUSTEST_DIALOG          102
#define IDS_APP_TITLE                   103
#define IDD_ABOUTBOX                    103
#define IDM_ABOUT                       104
#define IDM_EXIT                        105
#define IDI_GDIPLUSTEST                 107
#define IDI_SMALL                       108
#define IDC_GDIPLUSTEST                 109
#define IDR_MAINFRAME                   128
#define IDB_BITMAP1                     129
#define IDC_STATIC                      -1

// Next default values for new objects
//  
#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
#ifndef APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS
#define _APS_NO_MFC                     1
#define _APS_NEXT_RESOURCE_VALUE        130
#define _APS_NEXT_COMMAND_VALUE         32771
#define _APS_NEXT_CONTROL_VALUE         1000
#define _APS_NEXT_SYMED_VALUE           110
#endif
#endif
```

Anyone know why it would say IDB_BITMAP1 is undefined when it is clearly defined in resource.h?

Thank you.

I tried googling the error, but it was to no avail.

Comment: Presumably `resource.h` is not being included in `gdiplustest.cpp`.

Comment: In the image it seems like compilation succeeded (except for a few warnings), maybe it's just an editor (intellisense issue).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a [tour] and see [ask]. Specifically you'll need to provide a [mre], with all code (and errors) as text, not images.

Comment: The red squiggles are produced by Intellisense, which doesn't do a full compile, but only a quick scan to detect some errors. Sometimes it is too quick and makes mistakes, especially if macros are involved. If the full compile works, this warning can most often be ignored.

Answer (score -1):

The phenomenon also occurs to me. You can report this problem to the [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/cpp/report) and post link in the comment. Intellisense works fine after the build is complete.